# PhpMyAdmin database Export.

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, export, database-connection

I am exporting database from **PHPMYADMIN**. Database has 341 tables on remote server but when I import Sql file into local server PHPMYADMIN I got only 213 Tables.

**Question :**

How can I get all tables of database on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin should export all when you do export -> quick, but try to use the custom option and make sure all are selected. Also, may want to check the mysql mode (select @@global.sql_mode) of local and remote. If your local has default settings, there may be some tables with data in a column that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your database is pretty large then you may have more success with exporting it via the command line rather than phpMyAdmin:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USERANME -p DATABASE_NAME > output.sql
```

Run that, you'll be prompted for your database password and then you'll get output.sql containing your database

You can then import this using ..

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME --no-create-db < output.sql
```